# Questions about nested direct descendants in LESS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

So I was looking into some code recently, and trying to learn more about LESS, and there is one thing that I am not able to wrap my head around completely. I saw the use of something structured like:

```
.class{
    >*{
        /*some css*/
    }
}
```

NOTE: The `>*{}` is nested inside of the `.class` block

I think have an idea of what this is doing, but there are a couple things I don't understand.

What I think it's doing: I am assuming that it is taking all of the direct descendants of that class and styling them accordingly. so the actual(compiled) css might be something like `.class > *{}`

My questions:

1. Am I right in my assumption, or is this doing something completely different?
2. If that is correct, why does this statement not need the & in front of it like other concatenations?

I apologize if this is something that has come up before, I simply don't know what other way to ask google the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually as simple as:

Nested selector elements are *always* combined with whitespace. E.g. <sup>**[1a]:**</sup>

```
a {
   b {}
}
```

results in:

```
a b {}
```

Same way, <sup>**[1b]:**</sup>
:

```
a {
   > b {}
}
```

results in:

```
a > b {}
```

etc.

**---**

`&` has to be used *only* if you need to suppress that whitespace, as in <sup>**[2a]:**</sup>

```
a {
    &:hover {}
}
```

for:

```
a:hover {}
```

*Or* if parent selector elements are not to be placed in front, <sup>**[2b]:**</sup>

```
a { 
   b & {}
}

c { 
   & & {}
}

d {
  & {}
}

e { 
   f ~ g:not(&) > & & + &&& {}
}

// etc.
```

resulting in:

```
b a {}
c c {}
d {}
f ~ g:not(e) > e e + eee {}
```

**---**

Combinators *never* affect anything and the only requirement is that a combinator must be followed by an identifier, e.g:

```
a { > b {} } // ok
a > { b {} } // error
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Your assumption is correct.
2. The `&` can be omitted from nested selectors that start with a combinator like `>` or `+`, or start with a compound selector where the intended result is a descendant combinator, such as

   ```
   .a { .b {} }
   ```

   resulting in `.a .b`.

Comment: Strangely, this does not appear to be mentioned in the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features), not that I can find anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the docs first, and couldn't find any significant reference to what I was looking for, or why that code compiled.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: It doesn't say anywhere that & can be omitted when the nested rule explicitly begins with a combinator. Instead, it has multiple examples of things like & > & and & + &.

Comment: You misassumtion is that you thought that a combinator makes it different. But the docs never say anything like this too.

Comment: Then the documentation is vague and can be interpreted both ways.

Comment: I'm not the author of the LESS docs, so there's not much that I can do directly.

Comment: @BoltClock You can make pull requests on the [less-docs](https://github.com/less/less-docs) GitHub repository

Comment: @TylerH not that I'd want to. I'd much rather contribute where it counts.